# error on loading url images in codename one app how can i solve this

Tags: image, codenameone

Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - create image failed for the given image data of length: 1420

```
 EncodedImage placeholder = (EncodedImage) initForm.theme.getImage("avater.png");
        icon1 = URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, "tyrion",  "https://www.dropbox.com/s/52tu8jkqg1pikvw/jpeg?dl=1");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a connectivity issue. I looked at the file and it's a 16k file yet you downloaded only 1,420 bytes so you got an error. I'm guessing that the link is redirecting and we get an HTML error page which is what you see.

It's also possible that this failed to you once and you're now still looking at the cached failed download.

The downloaded file should be in your `.cn1` directory (assuming this is on the simulator) under the name "tyrion". First try to just delete it.

If this doesn't help look at it's contents, it could be an HTML error file.

Comment: yah because when it loads the image I get a blank-white image and that's what I even found in my home directory in the Cn1. folder

Comment: Thanks, Shai: I think my code is ok you were right it was the Image link network because I kept on deleting the files for the home directory Cn1 folder and rerunning the app and some image sare now ok